# vba Excel/Word cant jump to bookmark

Tags: vba

```
Dim AppWD As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim objDocProdTP As Object
...
Set AppWD = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Word als Object starten
AppWD.Visible = True
Set objDocProdTP = AppWD.documents.Open(workPath & "\vorlagen\LFPostTemplate.docx")
Set objDoc = AppWD.documents.Open(workPath & "\vorlagen\LFTemplate2.docx")
...
MsgBox (objDoc.Bookmarks.Count)
objDoc.Goto what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="lblSFirma"
```

The MSGBox returns 11 Bookmarks (with matches with the total number of Bookmarks in LFPostTemplate.docx )

But every Bookmarkname i try returns "This bookmark does not exist"

I quess the problem is quite simple... But google dont seem to have any solution for me

Comment: Are you sure bookmark `lblSFirma` exits in `LFTemplate2`? Try `Dim b as Bookmark: For each b in objDoc.Bookmarks: Debug.Print b.Name: Next` and check current bookmarks name.

Comment: `The MSGBox returns 11 Bookmarks (with matches with the total number of Bookmarks in LFPostTemplate.docx )` ??? Maybe, nut note that objDoc is `LFTemplate2`!

Answer (score 2):

You start Word by late binding (from Excel?), so I assume word constants may not be defined. Try using -1 instead of `wdGotoBookmark`.

```
objDoc.Goto what:=-1, Name:="lblSFirma"
```

(Or you can set a reference to *Microsoft Word xx.xx Object Library*, then the constants are available)

Comment: Great if it works. Please mark the answer as "accepted" so others can see that this question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I got the code below working in Excel 2010.  I toggle the window view mode to make the page my bookmark is on appear at the top of the window (where my bookmark is).

```
Public Sub OpenWordDocAndGotoBookmark(strDocPathAndName As String, strBookmark As String)
    Dim AppWD As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim objBookmark As Object

    Set AppWD = CreateObject("Word.Application") ' Start Word
    AppWD.Visible = True

    Set objDoc = AppWD.Documents.Open(strDocPathAndName)

    Set objBookmark = objDoc.Bookmarks(strBookmark)

    ' Move cursor to left of Bookmark
    objDoc.Range(objBookmark.Start, objBookmark.Start).Select

    ' Set window to make top of page with bookmark appear at top of window
    AppWD.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.PageFit = wdPageFitFullPage
    AppWD.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.PageFit = wdPageFitBestFit
End Sub
```